# Automating .Net 1.1 Web Applications deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, build-automation, asp.net-1.1

I have been researching for a little bit how to automate VS2003 web application projects.  "DevEnv.com" solution via command-line does require IIS and appropriate mapping which is a show stopper for tfs2012 team build box and possibly we have to build same projects from different branches (diff physical path to same virtual folder mapping issue).
The only alternative so far is to migrate away to a new project system.
I want to know if someone was able to get teambuild working with web applications projects without altering the code drastically (project system or .net target version).

PS: I am aware of MSBee and Nant but they do not offer much of a solution.

Comment: Is upgrading to .NET 2.0 an option? .NET 1.1 is a decade old, and is unsupported.

Comment: I wish... I'd be using TeamBuild 2012 by now ;-)

Comment: So I spent some time with Nant a bit further.  It appears that it does have WebMap property to compile web projects